# CUPS - use credentials from login to pass to samba server

Tags: linux, samba, cups

Everytime I print, CUPS asks me for authentication information to print to a SAMBA shared printer.  Is it possible to pass my credentials to the SAMBA share directly from whatever I used to authenticate with my session?

Comment: It's *supposed to* do this by default, at least if you are using GNOME.